# android buttons GPIO mappings

Tags: android

We are designing a h/w platform (ARM CPU) that will run android. we have defined some GPIO pins to act as android buttons (HOME, MENU, VOL+,...). 
How do we tell android what GPIO corresponds to what buttons? Looks like there is no way to have the f/w (u-boot) pass that info to android kernel.  I have looked in android kernel, but found nothing in ./drivers/..
thanks
-jfs

Comment: found it: it is defined in machine files in arch/arm/...

Comment: Please post your findings as an answer ! :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, configurations specific to your device, such as this, typically live in the device tree within the Android source.  In this case, you'll need to create a key layout file that maps the gpio index (For the ARM i.MX, the combo of GPIO block + pin) to the function you wish it to perform.

I'm not certain whether this is still relevant for the latest versions, but it is worth checking out.
https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files